# Correct (Best) way to register and retrieve Repositories in C#

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, repository-pattern

The project I'm working on has a lot of boilerplate code for passing Repository objects around. The parent object creates a repository, passes it to any utility / helper methods to do some specific work, then in the end the parent object calls commit or save on the repository. And many times these utility/helper methods calls other methods, which also requires the repository. For one, we are definitely using the Repository Pattern incorrectly, since many of these helper methods really just uses the repositories as a DAO or even just a DB connection, run a quick query and be done with it. My question is what is the best way to avoid having to pass these repositories around?

The most primitive way would be to create the repositories in these helper methods, then destroy them (using clauses), and there are obvious downsides to that, and it's against DRY.

I also see examples of people registering these repositories as services, and use them that way.

Please take thread safety into consideration.

What are the expert opinions on this? Any example would be much appreciated.

PS. I'm a senior level Java guy but almost entry level on C#, so any java-related comparison would be great too.

Comment: Rob Conery had a good IRepository example I cheated from.  When you utilize it, you're still having to call {IRepository}.CommitChanges(); or whatever, but it works well.  In web, you're going to register the lifetime of the IRepository to be InRequestContext() [from Ninject] or similar, but in WinForms, you're going to manage it more by hand, on your own.

Comment: Ah, that's exactly what I was wondering about. .NET has quite a few cool inject mechanisms for creating repositories for the per-request scenario, but I kinda hoped you could do the same thing with WinForms, at least for the cases where the Repo is used as a DAO, in a static like way. I shall keep hunting... Thx

Comment: If the Repository example is the one from Rob's (now quite old) videos , then it's a BAD example mainly because it was just a simple wrapper over Entity Framework, exposing IQueryable

Answer (score 2):

The 'correct' way to register and retrieve Repositories is with a DI Container (I recommend [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/GettingStarted)

```
builder.RegisterType<MyRepository>().AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

*InstancePerLifeTimeScope* means it's thread scoped so only one instance per thread. Every object needing the repository will have the repository interface as the constructor dependency. For some services, the repository can be a method argument.

The repository will use a (micro)ORM to 'talk' with the database. There are some cases where you need data or even some objects which can be retrieved directly from the db. In that case you have a service and not a repository, although both implementations (not interfaces) belong in the DAL.

I'm assuming that all the services and repositories are passed as abstractions, so every object needing a service or repository will know only about a IService or IRepository. The DI Container will inject the concrete types, the client objects don't need to know about those.